# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ruamel'

Tags: python

I'm using a Kubernetes inventory builder script found here: https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kubespray/blob/master/contrib/inventory_builder/inventory.py

On `line 36`, the ruamel YML library is imported using the code `from ruamel.yaml import YAML`. This library can be found here: https://pypi.org/project/ruamel.yaml/

On my OSX device (`Mojave 10.14.3`), if I run `pip list`, I can clearly see the most up to date version of `ruamel.yaml`:

[image: pip list]

If I run `pip show ruamel.yaml`, I get the following output:

[image: pip show ruamel.yaml]

I'm running the script with this command: `CONFIG_FILE=inventory/mycluster/hosts.ini python3 contrib/inventory_builder/inventory.py 10.0.0.1 10.0.0.2 10.0.0.4 10.0.0.5`

Bizarrely, it returns the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "contrib/inventory_builder/inventory.py", line 36, in <module>
    from ruamel.yaml import YAML
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ruamel'
```

I have very little experience with Python, so don't understand how this could be failing. Have I installed the library incorrectly or something? From the documentation on the `ruamel.yml` project page, it looks like the script is calling the library as it should be.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I suspect `pip` is pointing at Python 2. What does `pip3 list` show?

Comment: I agree with @DanielRoseman. Try install `ruamel.yaml` with command `pip3 install ruamel.yaml` instead to install the package specifically for Python3.

Comment: You're both right - `pip3` showed no `ruamel` module, so I've used `pip3 install` and now it's working. Would one of you like to put this in as an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`pip` is set to point to the Python 2 installation. To install the library under Python 3, do `pip3 install ruamel.yml`.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, I was installing this with `pip3 install ruamel.yaml`, and it was puting the package in `/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/`, but the `python3` binary on the machine was pinned to Python 3.7, so trying to import that module was sending the `ModuleNotFoundError` message.

What helped to fix this, was to install the module with `python3 -m pip install ruamel.yaml`, running pip via the python3 binary makes sure it runs on the same version, in this case 3.7, and gets installed via the correct version number site-packages.

Answer (score 1):

you're using python 3 and want to use the package that is with python 2. Go to the directory where your python 3 is, navigate to Scripts and use the pip in there to install the needed library.

Answer (score 0):

This helped me (adding version number to python):

```
CONFIG_FILE=inventory/mycluster/hosts.yaml python3.6 contrib/inventory_builder/inventory.py ${IPS[@]}
```

Answer (score 0):

[python 3.10.x].
There is no package called ruamel.yaml
what worked is `pip install ruamel-yaml`