# Facing problem in azure ml pipeline creation

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-machine-learning-service, azureml-python-sdk

When creating the container image, it is showing below error in ACI instance.
Any help is appreciated.

```
Exception in worker process
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/miniconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 557, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/opt/miniconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 126, in init_process
    self.load_wsgi()
  File "/opt/miniconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 136, in load_wsgi
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/opt/miniconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/opt/miniconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 65, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/opt/miniconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/opt/miniconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 357, in import_app
    __import__(module)
  File "/var/azureml-server/wsgi.py", line 1, in <module>
    import create_app
  File "/var/azureml-server/create_app.py", line 3, in <module>
    from app import main
  File "/var/azureml-server/app.py", line 31, in <module>
    import main as user_main
  File "/var/azureml-app/main.py", line 12, in <module>
    driver_module_spec.loader.exec_module(driver_module)
  File "/var/azureml-app/score.py", line 30, in <module>
    from azureml.core.model import Model
  File "/opt/miniconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azureml/core/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from .workspace import Workspace
  File "/opt/miniconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azureml/core/workspace.py", line 34, in <module>
    from azureml.core.image import Image
  File "/opt/miniconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azureml/core/image/__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
    from .image import Image
  File "/opt/miniconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azureml/core/image/image.py", line 19, in <module>
    from azureml.core.model import Model
  File "/opt/miniconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azureml/core/model.py", line 40, in <module>
    from azureml.core.environment import Environment
  File "/opt/miniconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azureml/core/environment.py", line 31, in <module>
    from azureml.core.conda_dependencies import CondaDependencies, PYTHON_DEFAULT_VERSION
  File "/opt/miniconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azureml/core/conda_dependencies.py", line 11, in 
import ruamel.yaml
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ruamel'
```

The image is created without any error, but it is failing in the build process.

Comment: The last line of the log contains the main cause of the error. Do you have this module installed?

Comment: Just checking in to see whether this issue is still blocking you now? Any update for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

According to the error message, it seems that missing the module `ruamle`, we could run the cmd `pip install ruamel.yml` to install the module, then run the pipeline again.

In addition, I found a similar ticket, You could also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55454514/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-ruamel) for more details.